# Looking for a "realistic" Hercules movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, hercules

This is a movie I've only heard a couple of details about a while back, but it's intrigued me ever since.  It's a live-action movie about Hercules but, according to what I heard, it's somewhat realistic in terms of the events Hercules encounters.  The only example I remember is that Hercules is drugged or something and fights three dogs, but he sees it as being a three-headed dog instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is *[Hercules](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1267297/)* (2014), starring Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson.

> Having endured his legendary twelve labors, Hercules, the Greek demigod, has his life as a sword-for-hire tested when the King of Thrace and his daughter seek his aid in defeating a tyrannical warlord.

There's a scene where Hercules thinks he sees the Cerberus standing over the bodies of his late wife and children, but it turns out to be a hallucination.

Later in the film, he's forced to fight three ferocious wolves.

> In the same scene, it's revealed that some time prior to the events of the film itself, the three wolves were unleashed upon Hercules' wife and children by King Eurystheus, in an attempt to make it look like Hercules had murdered his own family, thereby blackening his name. Hercules was drugged so that he couldn't protect his family, but he apparently witnessed their deaths in a drugged stupor, and this is why he subsequently had recurring dreams/hallucinations of a three-headed wolf standing over their bodies.

In general, this movie does attempt to play down the supernatural aspects of Greek myth, suggesting that Hercules is not actually the son of Zeus, that he relies on a band of loyal allies (Autolycus, Atalanta, Iolaus, etc)  rather than accomplishing everything on his own, and that there may be no actual gods or monsters.

[This review](https://awesomelyshitty.wordpress.com/2015/03/15/its-heracles-not-hercules/) talks a little bit more about that.

> The most annoying thing of all, as if there hasn’t already been a laundry list of annoying things, is the film’s insistence that Heracles is mortal and not a demi-god. The 12 labors happened, but were played up by rumor and legend. The Hydra just turned out to be some dude wearing a sea-serpant mask (this is never explained), and Cerberus (the famous three-headed hound of Hades) is actually just three dogs. The movie wants to be realistic, but it can’t be realistic with wire-fu battles, cheesy one-liners, and ancient Greeks being played by American and British actors.

Comment: Yep, that looks like it, thanks!  I heard rave reviews about it when I first heard about it, so that's interesting to know about how it was received!

Comment: Its a good movie, but it turns Hercules the Demi-God of Mythology into... Hercules, the tough mercenary-for-hire. People expecting Hercules and meeting Rambo are naturally disappointed.